# Combining 2 variables in to 1 to call an ID

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create the following code in a function that will repeat it a variable number of times

```
myId##.className = myId##.className.replace(' class1',' class2')
```

so far I have come up with the following but it is not working.

```
function toggle(partId,orig,rep,itr)
{
var partId; // Begining of Id string
var orig;  // Original Class
var rep;  // Replacement Class
var itr;  // Total number to be iterated through
var num = 1; // Starting at 1
var finalId; // for partId + num
while (num<=itr)
 {
 finalId = partId + num;
 finalId.className = finalId.className.replace(orig,rep);
 num++;
 }
}
```

I then implemented it like so.

```
<area shape="circle" coords="933,92,23" 
      alt="myAlt" href="#none" 
      onmouseover="toggle('myPartId',' class1',' class2',5)"
      onmouseout="toggle('myPartId',' class1',' class2',5)" />
```

So I thought I could supplement the ID node in `className` and I am ether doing it wrong or I am wrong in that it can not be done.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is not clear. The second snippet uses chang() but the final snippet calls toggle()? What are you expecting for input and output if it were working correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your while loop with this

```
var el;
while (num<=itr)
 {
 finalId = partId + num;
 el = document.getElementById(finalId);
 el.className = el.className.replace(orig,rep);
 num++;
 }
}
```

and call the `chang` method and not the `toggle`.. (*unless it is a fault of the example here..*)

Answer (score 0):

You never get the object the ID points to.
Add an getElementById and try it.

```
 {
 finalId = partId + num;
 var element = document.getElementById(finalId);
 element.className = element.className.replace(orig,rep);
 num++;
 }
```